# Solvability of the Diophantine equation $x^{2} - y^{2} = 4z^{n}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

It is known that for every integer $z$ there are integers $x, y$ such that $x^{2} - y^{2} = z^{3}.$ In fact, given an integer $z$, taking $x := z(z+1)/2$ and $y := z(z-1)/2$ suffices.

But how is the integer solvability of the equation $x^{2} - y^{2} = 4z^{n}$ when $n \geq 5$? By intuition it seems that this Diophantine equation is unsolvable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every integer number $n$ that is not of the form $4k+2$ can be expressed as the difference of two squares. For instance:
$$ x= z^n+1, \quad y=z^n-1 $$
is always a solution of:
$$ x^2-y^2 = 4z^n. $$

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks!

Comment: Is it also necessary?

Comment: @Chou: It is a necessary condition because $x^2-y^2\not\equiv 2\pmod{4}$. It is a sufficient condition since $n=d_1\cdot d_2$ and $d_1\equiv d_2\pmod{2}$ grant that $x=\frac{d_1+d_2}{2}$ and $y=\frac{d_1-d_2}{2}$ fulfill $x^2-y^2=n$.